# Check if a given class meets the constraints of a generic type

Tags: java, generics

I need to create several classes which all suppose to have a certain class member which extends another class, so I'm trying to create another super class which all of them will inherit from.

I want this super class to hold a correct instance of the needed type which the user can get.

I'm making a class which gets a Class object and then I want to instantiate an object of that class but only if it meets the same constraints as the generic type, but I'm not sure how to check it.

The class is something like this:

```
public class GenericClass<T extends SomeClass<S> & AnotherClass<S>, S extends Object> 
{
    protected T myObject;

    public GenericClass(Class objectClass)
    {
        //this line is the problem
        if(T.isAssignableFrom(objectClass))
        {
            try
            {
                myObject= (T) objectClass.newInstance();

            }
            catch (InstantiationException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

   public T getMyObject()
   {
       return myObject;
   }
 }
```

The problematic line is giving the error:

> The method isAssignableFrom(Class) is undefined for the type T

So how can I check if the class is indeed of a type of a child of T and meet its constraint? Should I just use the `catch` block for the check?

Comment: Use `Class<? extends T>` as a parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So how can I check if the class is indeed of a type of a child of T and meet its constraint?

The compiler will check this if you use the generic type (also you will not need the cast)

```
public GenericClass(Class<T> objectClass) {
  try {
    myObject = objectClass.newInstance();

  } catch (InstantiationException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```